# Touchpad issues on ThinkPad E14 Gen 4 with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, touchpad, thinkpad

**TL;DR** I need ELAN touchpad/TrackPoint drivers for Ubuntu 22.04 on ThinkPad E14 Gen 4, or a suitable alternative, to fix touchpad stability in a dual-booted system. What to do?

I have a ThinkPad E14 Gen 4 (Intel), and I am dual-booting Windows 11 Pro and Ubuntu 22.04 on it. I did not want to mix up the OSes in any way, and wanted to keep Windows' BitLocker on, so I got a second SSD installed in my laptop by Lenovo, and Ubuntu lives there.

For the most part, everything is fantastic, even the fingerprint reader. However, I am running into an issue with my touchpad/TrackPoint. At any given time, if it's working fine, it starts misbehaving if I boot from one OS to another, and then back to the first one. The behaviour presents itself in one of two ways, seemingly at random:

- The touchpad and TrackPoint stop working altogether
- The scrolling and multi-touch functionality of the touchpad stop working, but clicking and dragging elements works fine. The TrackPoint also stops scrolling.

I tried several times to (re)install drivers in Windows, and it never helps. The only thing that works is going into UEFI Diagnostics and resetting the mouse, and this is a temporary solution.

According to Lenovo support, this is a software problem because they don't provide touchpad drivers for my laptop on Ubuntu, because I got this device built to custom specs instead of ordering a standard one. Their advice is that I should boot one OS at a time, and not frequently switch. However, I genuinely need both: I'm an electrical engineering student and our uni uses some Windows-only designing/simulation software; I develop projects with embedded systems and ROS2 on Linux, and it's a pain to do it via virtualization/WSL.

How can I get my trackpad working in a stable way? Note that I'm comfortable in a Linux terminal due to experience from WSL, Docker, and Raspberry Pi, but I'm very new to Linux GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

I have the E14 Gen 4 with AMD but otherwise same setup as you (Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11), and it also has an Elantech Touchpad/Trackpoint. I updated the BIOS from Windows the first time I used it, and use the hwe kernel in Ubuntu. For me, in general, the Touchpad and Trackpoint work. It just has glitchy behavior sometimes with button bouncing in Ubuntu, and it reports some problems in the kernel log, but it can be used. However, maybe you need to make sure to shutdown Windows correctly before booting into Linux. I always do that.

So the suggested solution is to:

- Run a BIOS Update from Windows, also run all other possible firmware updates from there (not all is available in Linux/Ubuntu)
- Use the Ubuntu hwe kernel, which is more recent to support more recent hardware. You can do that by installing the linux-generic-hwe-22.04 package
- Always make sure to shutdown Windows completely before booting into Ubuntu again